# Sync App-Backend user table with wordpress login

Tags: php, django, wordpress, backend, endpoint

I programmed a Backend for an app. In the Backend is of course the login/registration endpoint.

The problem is that my client had the new idea of synchronizing his Wordpress Blog with the app. And now he wants that when an user registers himself in the App, then he can log in the Wordpress and when an user registers himself in the Wordpress Blog, he can log in the App.

My problem is that I'm not specialized either in Wordpress nor in PHP. I was watching the wp-login.php file, but didn't find a good result.

I'm thinking of using the Backend Endpoint with Wordpress, I can guess that Wordpress could work as a client. Then I could use the same Login-Backend-Function with the App and with Wordpress and it should work.

I was reading [this](http://techattitude.com/tips-tricks-and-hacks/how-to-remotely-create-a-user-on-your-wordpress-website-using-json-api-request/) kind of post in Internet, but is not that way, I don't want to register an user in Wordpress from the app, but the other way, I would like to register an user in the App or in Wordpress and log him in the App or Wordpress, but using the Django Endpoints of the Backend.

I did't think that it would be so complicated.

Maybe someone already tried something like that and can say me how I should program it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued searching in Internet and found this [post](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-1-replace-the-login-page--cms-23627).

Then, I easy changed the `do_register_user` function of the second page of the post the way I needed.